# How to manage configuration for Webpack/Electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron

I am using Webpack 2 and Electron to build nodejs application on Mac.

In my project in the root I have directory 'data' where I store configuration in a json like data/configurations/files.json (in practices there are different files with dynamic names)

After webpackaing though when I call: `fs.readdirSync(remote.app.getAppPath());` to get files in the root I get only these packed: `[ "default_app.js", "icon.png", "index.html", "main.js", "package.json", "renderer.js" ]`

`path.join(remote.app.getAppPath(), 'data/tests/groups.json');` called with FS ReadSync leads to an issue `Error: ENOENT, data/tests/groups.json not found in /Users/myuser/myproject/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.‌​app/Contents/Resourc‌​es/default_app.asar`. So it seems that the whole data folder is not picked up by webpacker.

Webpack config is using `json-loader` and I did not find any documentation mentioning anything special about including specific files or jsons. Or do I have to reference json files in my code differently as they might be packed under main.js.

What is the best practice for Electron/Webpack for managing JSON config files? Am I doing something wrong when webpacking the project?

My project is based of https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue using webpack/electron/vue

Comment: Is this just an opinion question?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Is there an actual problem to be solved here or do you just want an opinion on how to write configs?

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear about what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried and what issue you are facing so that we can better help you. I think what you might want is [Webpack's require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) which you can use to dynamically load all (json) files in a directory.

Comment: I updated with specific code and error message. I am trying to use fs.readFileSync to read json from data folder but the data folder does not seem to be included by webpacker

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### The Webpack Misconception

One thing to understand upfront is that `webpack` does not bundle files required through `fs` or other modules that ask for a path to a file. These type of assets are commonly labeled as **Static Assets**, as they are not bundled in any way. `webpack` will only bundle files that are `require`d or `import`ed (ES6). Furthermore, depending on your `webpack` configuration, your project root may not always match what is output within your production builds.

Based on the electron-vue documentation's **Project Structure/File Tree**, you will find that only `webpack` bundles and the `static/` directory are made available in production builds. electron-vue also has a handy [`__static`](https://simulatedgreg.gitbooks.io/electron-vue/content/en/using-static-assets.html#use-case-within-js-with-fspath-and-static) global variable that can provide a path to that `static/` folder within both development and production. You can use this variable similar to how one would with `__dirname` and `path.join` to access your JSON files, or really any files.

## A Solution to Static Assets

It seems the current version of the [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) boilerplate already has this solved for you, but I'm going to describe how this is setup with `webpack` as it can apply to not only JSON files and how it can also apply for any `webpack` + `electron` setup. The following solution assumes your `webpack` build outputs to a separate folder, which we'll use `dist/` in this case, assumes your `webpack` configuration is located in your project's root directory, and assumes `process.env.NODE_ENV` is set to `development` during development.

### The `static/` directory

During development we need a place to store our static assets, so let's place them in a directory called `static/`. Here we can put files, such as JSONs, that we know we will need to read with `fs` or some other module that requires a full path to the file.

Now we need to make that `static/` assets directory available in production builds.

> But `webpack` isn't handling this folder at all, what can we do?

Let's use the simple `copy-webpack-plugin`. Within our `webpack` configuration file we can add this plugin when building **for production** and configure it to copy the `static/` folder into our `dist/` folder.

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {
      from: path.join(__dirname, '/static'),
      to: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/static'),
      ignore: ['.*']
    }
])
```

> Okay so the assets are in production, but how do I get a path to this folder in both development and production?

### Creating a global `__static` variable

> What's the point of making this `__static` variable?

1. Using `__dirname` is not reliable in `webpack` + `electron` setups. During development `__dirname` *could* be in reference to a directory that exists in your `src/` files. In production, since `webpack` bundles our `src/` files into one script, that path you formed to get to `static/` doesn't exist anymore. Furthermore, those files you put inside `src/` that were not `require`d or `import`ed never make it to your production build.
2. When handling the project structure differences from development and production, trying to get a path to `static/` will be highly annoying during development having to always check your `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

#### So let's simplify this by creating one *source of truth*.

Using the `webpack.DefinePlugin` we can set our `__static` variable **only in development** to yield a path that points to `<projectRoot>/static/`. Depending if you have multiple `webpack` configurations, you can apply this for both a `main` and `renderer` process configuration.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    '__static': `"${path.join(__dirname, '/static').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')}"`
})
```

In production, we need to set the `__static` variable manually in our code. Here's what we can do...

**index.html** (`renderer` process)

```
<!-- Set `__static` path to static files in production -->
<script>
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') window.__static = require('path').join(__dirname, '/static').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
</script>
<!-- import webpack bundle -->
```

**main.js** (`main` process)

```
// Set `__static` path to static files in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
    global.__static = require('path').join(__dirname, '/static').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
}

// rest of application code below
```

#### Now start using your `__static` variable

Let's say we have a simple JSON file we need to read with `fs`, here's what we can accomplish now...

**`static/someFile.json`**

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

**`someScript.js`** (`renderer` or `main` process)

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

const someFile = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__static, '/someFile.json'), 'utf8')

console.log(JSON.parse(someFile))
// => { foo: bar }
```

### Conclusion

`webpack` was made to bundle assets together that are `require`d or `import`ed into one nice bundle. Assets referenced with `fs` or other modules that need a file path are considered **Static Assets**, and `webpack` does not directly handle these. Using `copy-webpack-plugin` and `webpack.DefinePlugin` we can setup a reliable `__static` variable that yields a path to our `static/` assets directory in both development and production.

To end, I personally haven't seen any other `webpack` + `electron` boilerplates handle this situation as it isn't a very common situation, but I think we can all agree that having one *source of truth* to a static assets directory is a wonderful approach to alleviate developer fatigue.

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion, (if there is any), might come from the fact that webpack not only "packs", embeds, things, code, etc... but also process content with its plugins.

html plugin being a good example, as it simply generates an html file at build-time.

And how this relates to the config file issue?, 
well depending on how you are "requiring" the "config" file, what plug-in you are using to process that content.

You could be embedding it, or simply loading it as text, from file system or http, or else...

In the case of a config file, that I guess you want it to be parsed at runtime,
otherwise it's just fancy hardcoding values that perhaps you could be better simply typing it in your source code as simple objects.

And again in that case I think webpack adds little to nothing to the runtime needs, as there is nothing to pre-pack to read at later use,

so I would possibly instead or "require"it,  i'll read it from the file system, with something like :

```
// read it parse it relative to appPath/cwd, 
const config = JSON.parse(
    fs.readfileSync( 
        path.join( app.getAppPath(), "config.json" ),
        "utf-8"
    ))
//note: look fs-extra, it does all that minus the app.path plus async
```

and electron will read it from the file system , or if using Electron.require will read it from  asar|fileSystem (in that order if I remember correctly, I could be wrong),

Comment: thank you for the help and I all check out fs-extra. Using path.join(remote.app.getAppPath(), 'data/tests/groups.json' leads to an issue Error: ENOENT, data/tests/groups.json not found in /Users/myuser/myproject/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar. So it seems that the whole data folder is not picked up by webpacker

Comment: you are welcome, check the path: 'node_modules/electron/dist'  , that is your current appPath, it will resolve differently when built-and-packed , ...perhaps while on development environment, you would like to use 'process.cwd', or  '__dirname' relative the file is trying to read the 'config-file'  instead, but that is up to you and your setup

Answer (score 1):

Webpack design philosophy is focused around very simple yet powerful concept:

> Transform and bundle everything that is actually used by your app.

To achieve that webpack introduces a powerful concept of dependency graph, which is able to manage virtually any kind of dependencies (not only *.js modules) by the means of so-called loaders.

The purpose of a loader is to transform your dependency in a way that makes statement `import smth from 'your_dependency'` meaningful. For instance, `json-loader` calls `JSON.parse(...)` during loading of *.json file and returns configuration object. Therefore, in order to  take advantage of webpack dependency resolution system for managing JSONs, start from installing `json-loader`:

```
$ npm install --save-dev json-loader
```

Then modify your `webpack.config.js` in the following way:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.json$/, use: 'json-loader'}
    ]
  }
  ...
};
```

At this point webpack should be able to resolve your JSON dependencies by their absolute paths, so the following should work (I assume here that you have a subdirectory `config` of your root context dir, containing file `sample.json`):

```
import sampleCfg from './config/sample.json';
```

But importing physical paths doesn't lead to elegant, robust and maintainable code (think of testability, for example), so it is considered a good practice to add aliases to your `webpack.config.js` for abstracting away your physical `.config/` folder from your import statements

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      cfg: './config'
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Then you'll be able to import your JSON config like that:

```
import sampleCfg from 'cfg/sample.json'
```

Finally, if you use `SimulatedGREG/electron-vue` Electron project template (as you mentioned in your post), then you have three webpack configuration files:

- `.electron-vue/webpack.web.config.js` - use this config file if you use this template just for ordinary web development (i.e. not for building native Electron projects);
- `.electron-vue/webpack.main.config.js` - use this file to configure webpack module that will run inside Electron's main process;
- `.electron-vue/webpack.renderer.config.js` - use this file for Electron's renderer process.

You can find more information on main and renderer processes in the [official Electron documentation](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/).